# Undefined variable 'json'

Tags: python, json, discord.py

I am coding my very fist Discord bot with python and if want to open a json file, I am getting the following error:

> Command raised an exception: NameError: name 'json' is not defined

The part of the script:

```
    @client.command(aliases=["bal"])
async def balance(ctx):
    await open_account(ctx.author)

    wallet_amt = users[str(user.id)["wallet"]]

    users = await get_bank_data()
    em = discord.Embed(title= f"{ctx.author.name}'s balance",color = discord.Color.red())
    em.add_field(name = "Balance", Value = wallet_amt)
    await ctx.send(embed = em)

async def open_account(user):
    users = await get_bank_data()
    if str(user.id in users):
        return False
    else:
        users[str(user.id)["wallet"]] = 0
    
    with open("balances.json", "w") as f:
        json.dump(users,f)
    return True

async def get_bank_data():
    with open("balances.json", "r") as f:
        users = json.load(f)
    return users
```

The json file:

```
{
    
}
```

Comment: did you import json in the beginning of your script with `import json`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To fix this you have to `import json`.

Answer (score 1):

Add `import json` to the top of the file. You haven't imported the JSON library and hence Python cannot recognize the name